# How to Test Spring MVC along with repository MongoDb

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

Can someone please help me with junit testing of service, controller and repository. I'm getting lots of error when I write test cases for service and controller class.

This is my service class

```
import com.controller.ValidatorClass;
import com.model.Entity;
import com.model.Status;
import com.repository.Repository;

@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private SequenceGeneratorService service;
    
    public ResponseEntity storeInDb(ExecutorEntity model) {
        ValidatorClass validation = new ValidatorClass();
        Map<String, String> objValidate = validation.getInput(model.getLink(), model.getUsername(), 
                model.getPassword(), model.getSolution());
        model.setId(service.getSequenceNumber(Entity.SEQUENCE_NAME));
        model.setStatus(Status.READY);
        repository.save(model);
        return new ResponseEntity(model, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public List<String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return ex.getBindingResult()
            .getAllErrors().stream()
            .map(ObjectError::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This is my controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/create")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity code(@Valid @RequestBody Entity model) {
        return service.storeInDb(model);
    }
```

My model class

```
@Transient  
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "user_sequence";

    @NotNull(message = "Name can not be Null")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "Password can not be Null")
    private String password;

    @NotNull(message = "Jenkins Link can not be Null")
    private String Link;

    @NotNull(message = "Solution can not be Null")
    private String solution;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private Status status; //enum class having READY and FAIL as values.
```

along with getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit is an extensive topic that you should read you up on: https://junit.org/junit5/

Please note that JUnit 5 is current version (I see that you've tagged your question with `junit4`).

I'll give you an idea on how to write some integration tests just to get you started. You will probably come across `TestRestTemplate` during your journey to wisdom, but it is now recommended to use `WebTestClient`.

Tests below will bring all parts of your application up-and-running. When you're getting more experienced, you will probably test slices of your application as well.

```
package no.yourcompany.yourapp.somepackage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class ExecutorControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void postExecutor_validModel_receiveOk() {
        webTestClient
                .post().uri("/executor")
                .bodyValue(createValidExecutorEntity())
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

    @Test
    public void postExecutor_validModel_receiveResponseEntity() {
        webTestClient
                .post().uri("/executor")
                .bodyValue(createValidExecutorEntity())
                .exchange()
                .expectBody(ResponseEntity.class)
                .value(responseEntity -> assertThat(responseEntity).isNotNull());
    }

    private static ExecutorEntity createValidExecutorEntity() {
        ....
    }
}
```

With dependency to `spring-boot-starter-test`, it is not necessary to add explicit dependencies to JUnit.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In order to use `WebTestClient`, add the following to your POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```